# hvplot is not working for pyinstaller. Invalid version: 'None'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, hvplot

I need bar diagram with different filter options that I want to create with python and make it available as an executable with pyinstaller.
So I came across hvplot and it works, very well, but it doesn't run as an executable at all.

The problem is the import of hvplot.pandas which leads to the following error when executing the executable:

```
 File "packaging\version.py", line 197, in __init__.
packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: 'None'
[15440] Failed to execute script 'fail' due to unhandled exception!
```

This can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import hvplot.pandas
from bokeh.sampledata.penguins import data as df

hvexplorer = hvplot.explorer(df)
hvexplorer.show()
```

I upgraded and re-installed packages without success.

Comment: Could you please also add the information about how you create the executable?

Comment: I'm facing the same error. Here is the pyinstaller command: `pyinstaller --onefile --console --icon images/logo.ico --name MyExeProgram src/mypackage/main.py`. Here are the dependencies I'm installing: `pip install pyinstaller bokeh==2.4.3 hvplot==0.8.3 holoviews==1.15.4 streamz==0.6.4`. I'm using python 3.7 and using the GitHub Actions `runs-on: windows-latest`

Comment: we fixed it by adding these pyinstaller flags `--collect-all holoviews --collect-all param` + updating to python 3.8 + pinning more dependencies `pip install pyinstaller bokeh==2.4.3 param==1.12.0 hvplot==0.8.3 holoviews==1.16.0 streamz==0.6.4 pandas==2.0.0 numpy==1.23.4`